# json_encode returns undefined with array of non-associative arrays

Tags: php, return, undefined, json

I try to encode data to JSON in PHP (Version 5.3.13) and send it to JavaScript.
**My problem is:**
When I encode an array of non-associative arrays, it returns undefined:

```
$arr = array(array(1, 2, 3));
echo json_encode($arr); // outputs nothing ("")
```

Can you help me?

**Edit**: my OS is FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE

**Edit**: If it can help, I use this in MODX Evo web-site. I used this php-script as calling it form web-page, and all works fine. But then I create a snipet whih contains 1 line of code - include of this php-script. Now I call a web-page with nothing but this snippet in content.
Logically it is the same thing, but now it's not working.

Comment: its returning json data..http://eval.in/31887

Comment: I highly doubt that...can you reproduce the problem on http://3v4l.org , http://ideone.com , http://codepad.org , or similar online fiddle site?

Comment: There is PHP version 5.4.6 and I have 5.3.13. I can't update it, because some other scripts can stop working.

Comment: @ВасилийВасильевич http://3v4l.org/NOag3 works on 5.3 too

Comment: Output for php 5.2.0 - http://3v4l.org/jBr55
[[1,2,3]]

Comment: Yes.. I have no idea what it could be :(

Comment: Worked on 5.3.13 http://3v4l.org/Nok0A

Comment: Yes, I've already test that in this fiddle.. Maybe it's some missed libs on server?

Comment: Your code is working fine. Perhaps you have another error on the page you are not seeing? Try to add a `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of the page. Perhaps its hidden content. Also if you have a JSON header your browser might not show it either

Comment: I've tested it with `error_reporting(-1);` and `header("text/html");` and there is no changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show all errors.
And use `var_dump` instead of `echo`.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$json = json_encode(array(array(1, 2, 3)));
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: I used all your advices and with `var_dump(json_encode($json))` is outputs `string(9) "" `. I don't understand what it means

Comment: Yes, `string(9) "" ` with empty string and space in the end

Comment: I think `string(9)` is the length of `[[1,2,3]]` encoded value.. But why is there an empty string?

Comment: `echo rawurlencode($json);` outputs `%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%5D` - valid encoded value

Comment: Are you checking this behavior on WebBrowser, or Commandline?

Comment: I checking in web browser because i need to use returned value in some web page

Comment: Testing in commandline outputs `Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode()`

Comment: Umm... I can't understand what happened, but the similar report was found: https://drupal.org/node/1673014

Comment: Yes, but problems are opposite - in browser it shows json version 1.2.1 and in command line I didn't see any json references

Comment: About `undefined function json_encode()`, it may be the **PHP bug**. If we can also get the same problem on the recent version, we should report it.

Comment: If it's PHP bug, should I reinstall PHP or it wouldn't help?

Comment: About `string(9) ""`, I can profess this problem was because of your browser... Oh, I forgot to include this; View **source** of this content.

Comment: The source is `string(9) ""` with line break in the end

Comment: `string(9) ""` means chars `s`, `t`, `r`, `i`, `n`, `g`, `(`, `9`, `)`, **SPACE**, `"`, `"`, **EOL** ? Weren't any chars found between  double quotation marks?

Comment: No, there is no any chars in quotes.. Maybe it's something with encoding or charset? I added header `Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` but had no changes

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. I've updated the question with some info, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your script is working fine.

```
[[1,2,3]] //Output
```

My PHP Version 5.3.8 please would you mind to mention your php version. 
May be your PHP version is less then 5.2

Comment: I mentioned it above - it's PHP 5.3.13

Comment: Oh sorry i had not notice! Your PHP version is ok